# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'invalid object name EmpUpdate'

Tags: c#, wcf

Service1.cs

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public getempupdate[] Update(string EName)
        {           
            {
                getempupdate g = new getempupdate();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EID, EName, EUpdate from EmpUpdates with (nolock) where EName = @EName", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EName", EName);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt); //Getting the error on this line
                con.Close();
                g.EmpUpdates = dt;
                return dt.ToList<getempupdate>().ToArray();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Master database is a SQL Server reserved database, not intented for user data.

Answer (score 0):

This would normally indicate that the table does not exist. Check you spelled it correctly.

Also looks like your connection string points to a database called 'master'. That's probably wrong. What is your database name?

Comment: hello Steve, my database name is EmployeeUpdate. Also I checked my table EmpUpdates does exist in database. I'm new to this, what should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: I got the issue i had forgotten to add my db name in the query above. Thanks for your help!